# Null values being interpolates as 0 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, null, values

I have  a file with data fields which I have imported as CSV. When I look at the Field Attribute Table, the empty fields appear clearly as NULL values. However when I interpolate the data, the NULL values are being t[image]reated as 0 (zero).

How do I get around that?

Comment: Which interpolation tool are you using?

Comment: I have used IDW interploation

Answer (score 2):

You could try to filter your data (in layer properties > source > Query Builder with the expression : "MY_FIELD" is not NULL) to remove the null value before interpolating

Comment: Thank you. That really worked for me. But I find it counter intuitive. I expected the interpolation routine to honor the null values as NULL. I am new to QGIS.